# write a program in c# for following scenario

Tags: multithreading

Consider a clowder consisting of 50 cats. There are 5 bowls of cat food to feed them. Each of the bowl has a capacity to feed the mentioned number of cats. No two cats can eat from the same bowl at the same time. One cat can eat from one bowl only. If there is no bowl free, the cat will have to wait until any of the bowls gets free. The cats can come and check periodically to check if a bowl is free.   Simulate the above situation in C#. The cats would be represented using threads. The bowls may be mimicked using arrays of the size of feeding capacity. The eating is to be simulated using a feed_cat method. While a cat is being fed the method causes the thread to sleep for 1000 milli seconds.  Write a main method that creates all the 50 threads named as “Thread_1”, “Thread_2” and so on. The method feed_cat is passed to the threads.  The name of the currently active thread is to be printed on the console.     bowl1=10,bowl2=15,bowl3=12,bowl4=14,bowl5=9

Comment: Why does this feel like a homework assignment? Have to done anything thus far? In that case what have you done? Please provide the code.

Comment: dunya wich koi programmer jamia e ni jira inu solve kr leway ,,,lath di lanat   eh software engineeran ty... 5 rupy ly lao ty bnra dio program

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Semaphore Bouncer { get; set; }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create the semaphore with 3 slots, where 3 are available.
        Bouncer = new Semaphore(3, 3);

        // Open the feedcat.
        feedcat();

    } 

    public static void feedcat()
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
        {

            if (i <= 10)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(cat));
                thread.Start(i);
            }
            else if(i>10 && i<=25)
            {
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(cat1));
                thread1.Start(i);
            }
            else if (i>25 && i<=37) { 
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(cat2));
            thread2.Start(i);
            }
            else if (i > 37 && i<=51)
            {
                Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(cat3));
                thread3.Start(i);
            }
            else 
            {
                Thread thread4 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(cat4));
                thread4.Start(i);
            }

        }
    }


    public static void cat(object args)
    {
        // Wait to enter the Bowl (a semaphore to be released).
        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is waiting to entering the Bowl.", args);
        Bouncer.WaitOne();


        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is eating.", args);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Let one cat out (release one semaphore).
        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is leaving the Bowl1.", args);
        Bouncer.Release(1);
        //Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter Key for Move On");
    }
    public static void cat1(object args)
    {
        // Wait to enter the Bowl (a semaphore to be released).
        Console.WriteLine("Cat {0} is waiting to entering the Bowl.", args);
        Bouncer.WaitOne();



        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is eating.", args);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Let one cat out (release one semaphore).
        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is leaving the Bowl2.", args);
        Bouncer.Release(1);
        //Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter Key for Move On");
    }


    public static void cat2(object args)
    {
        // Wait to enter the Bowl (a semaphore to be released).
        Console.WriteLine("Cat {0} is waiting to entering the Bowl.", args);
        Bouncer.WaitOne();


        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is eating.", args);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Let one cat out (release one semaphore).
        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is leaving the Bowl3.", args);
        Bouncer.Release(1);
       // Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter Key for Move On");
    }
    public static void cat3(object args)
    {
        // Wait to enter the Bowl (a semaphore to be released).
        Console.WriteLine("Cat {0} is waiting to entering the Bowl.", args);
        Bouncer.WaitOne();


        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is eating.", args);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Let one cat out (release one semaphore).
        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is leaving the Bowl4.", args);
        Bouncer.Release(1);
       // Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter Key for Move On");
    }
    public static void cat4(object args)
    {
        // Wait to enter the Bowl (a semaphore to be released).
        Console.WriteLine("Cat {0} is waiting to entering the Bowl.", args);
        Bouncer.WaitOne();


        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is eating.", args);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Let one cat out (release one semaphore).
        Console.WriteLine("cat {0} is leaving the Bowl5.", args);
        Bouncer.Release(1);
       // Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter Key for Move On");
    }
}
```